# Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 API changes issue

Tags: winapi, windows-phone-8.1, compatibility

I have a full fledged app built for windows 8.1...

Through my research, I discovered that the api changes between 8.1 and 10 is nt that much and an app built for 8.1 will work on 10..

So my question now is will a windows 10 app work on windows 8.1?

If yes, how can I go about it?

Comment: Backward compatibility is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a report on changes for WinAPI 8 vs WinAPI 10 that may help you to discover differences in details. It's available on [this page](http://abi-laboratory.pro/compatibility/Windows_8.1_to_Windows_10_1511_10586.494/x86_64/abi_compat_report.html). The report is generated with the help of the [ABI-CC](https://github.com/lvc/abi-compliance-checker) tool.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since apps built for WP8.1 don't work on WP8, then I doubt that Windows 10 Mobile apps will work on WP8.1. As far as I'm aware, there are more differences between those two systems' API than between 8.1 and 8.0

Btw, are you asking about the desktop systems or the mobile ones (as the tag you used suggests)?

Comment: Asking about windows phone app